# Use a Reference Class as Levels of a Factor

Tags: r, reference-class

Does anyone have any experience using Reference Classes as the levels of a factor? This is one step in my goal of adding "foreign-key-like" support to a `data.frame` in one of my packages.

I'm ultimately looking to create a `data.frame` which can store, as integers, the codes associated with a factor, but the levels of this factor are actually Reference Class objects, rather than the character vectors factors typically use. I've been able to find some information on using S4 objects as levels of a factor, but the techniques don't seem to be working for Reference Classes.

For instance, a simple:

```
> myClass <- setRefClass("MyClass", fields=list(a="numeric", b="character"))
> myObj <- myClass$new(a=1, b="test")
> factor(myObj)
Error in unique.default(x) : unique() applies only to vectors
> as.character(myObj)
Error in as.vector(x, "character") : 
  cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'character'
> as.character.MyClass <- function(x){ x$b }
> as.character(myObj)
[1] "test"
> factor(myObj)
Error in unique.default(x) : unique() applies only to vectors
>
> unique.MyClass <- function (x, incomparables = FALSE, ...) { unique(as.character(x)) }
> factor(myObj)
Error in as.vector(x, mode) : invalid 'mode' argument
> traceback()
2: as.vector(exclude, typeof(x))
1: factor(myObj)
```

doesn't seem to get anything working. It looks like, at my best, I can get to the line in `factor()` which analyzes the `exclude` parameter:

```
exclude <- as.vector(exclude, typeof(x))
```

at which point everything falls apart, since I'm not allowed to create a vector of type "S4".

Any thoughts on how to solve this or -- even better -- alternative approaches to map an integer to an Reference Class object in a `data.frame`-friendly way would be much appreciated!

---

**Edit:** In response to @Aaron's question below:

The simple solution here would be to just store integers in the `data.frame` and then maintain a separate list/`data.frame` responsible for mapping those IDs to some other data (such as Reference Class objects). This would maintain all of the necessary data to accomplish what I need, but would be less elegant, to me, for a couple of reasons:

1. I'm envisioning a solution that would allow me to print out some portion of the Reference Class object itself, rather than the ID. For instance, if I'm mapping employee IDs (integer) to an "Employee" class, I would like my `data.frame` to print the names of the employees, rather than their IDs.
2. I'd like to be able to extract the objects directly from the `data.frame`. In the same way that `as.character(myDataFrame$someColumn)` would give me the *labels* of that column (assuming it's a factor) rather than the underlying integers actually being stored in the `data.frame`.

Again, I'm very open to alternative solutions to this problem if there's a better way to go about it!

Comment: OK, I must admit I've been following this question in hopes of reading the answers but there aren't any yet, so I'll ask what (to me) seems like an obvious question, but I don't know that much about Reference Classes or what `data-frame`-friendly means.  It seems the simple solution is to just use an ordinary integer in the data frame and have the list of corresponding objects external to it.  What's the downside of that for you?

Comment: Thanks, @Aaron. I've added some information to the original question to (hopefully) clarify why I want a factor-like object and the benefits I'm envisioning from being "data.frame-friendly."

Comment: To split your problems, you can create a object-valued factor by crearting it from the character representation first, then substituting the levels attribute with the actual objects. Then you have two sub-problems. One is creating these automatically, either by tweaking the `factor` function, or by writing your own function to build them. The other is making sure that these beasts get printed in a reasonable way, which does not work out of the box for their occurrence in a `data.frame`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be done by making a new class, say, `myFactor`, with the necessary methods; `format` seems to be the one you need for printing in a data frame; you could easily add `print` or other methods of your choice.  I'm most comfortable with S3 methods, so that's what I've done here.

Here I set up both your reference class and the `format` function for the `myFactor` class.

```
myClass <- setRefClass("MyClass", fields=list(a="numeric", b="character"))
format.myFactor <- function(obj, ...) {
  n <- sapply(levels(obj), function(x) x[["b"]])
  n[obj]
}
```

Here I make two new reference objects, and use them as levels of my new `myFactor` object.

```
myObj <- myClass$new(a=1, b="test")
myObj2 <- myClass$new(a=4, b="testagain")
foo <- structure(c(2,1,2), levels=c(myObj, myObj2), class=c("myFactor","numeric"))
d <- data.frame(x=foo)
```

It then prints nicely.

```
> d
          x
1 testagain
2      test
3 testagain
```